# Python increment part of an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to increment part of an array in python as fast as possible. I use a simple loop :

```
>>> test = [0,0,0,0,0]
>>> for i in xrange(1, 3):
    test[i] += 1

>>> test
[0,1,1,0,0]
```

In my program the test list contains several millions elements. Maybe numpy could be the solution ?

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy is indeed a solution:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(test)
arr[1:3] += 1
```

You can use `arr.tolist()` if you really need to go back to a `list` but better would be to use a NumPy array right from the start, wherever you get your data.

Comment: @MarcMonot: thank you, perhaps you could upvote to offset the beautiful snowflake that downvoted this, and accept it if your problem is resolved by this.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I already tried by I can't up vote for that I need 15 reputations :)

Comment: Ah ok, I marked the answer and earn reputation, then I vote up :) Thanks again.